# How to implement search like facebook, that will search through my contacts from my android?

Tags: android, search, android-contacts

i want to bind a name into a textview in android if it's in contact book, 
I want to implement a search, something like facebook search when you start typing the name of a contact a list under the search to  show up. that list should show from my phone contats, if a name is not in the contacts, and if the name is not in the contacts what u write that should bind into the textview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example which shows one can implement contacts auto-complete in Android: http://lemonbloggywog.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/customer-autocomplete-contacts-android/

[image: Contacts autocomplete]

Another example: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/